# Get a string from a text field using twig and craft CMS

Tags: html, css, twig

I am using twig and craft CMS.

How can I access just one word from a text field and underline it?
As an example of what I want the result to be, I have provided a HTML and CSS code.

```
<p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    <span>printing</span> and
    <span>typesetting</span> industry.
</p>
```

```
span {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

That's the code that I use in twig

```
{% for text in texts %}
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
        <h1>{{ text.title }}</h1>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How will or are you determining which word to underline?

Comment: @DarkBee it's going to be chosen depending on the cotext of the text. For now the goal is to access any element as a separated from the others and work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way around it by changing the field type to **Redactor**. This way I was able to edit the text with HTML.
It is also possible to edit the **Redactor config file** (craft/config/redactor/) and add buttons for editting.

```
"buttons": ["bold", "italic", "underline"]
```

This is the [documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/2.x/rich-text-fields.html#redactor-configs) I used.

Answer (score 3):

The text field may be divided into an array of words using Twig's `split` filter, and you can then use the array's index to get the desired word.

Comment: I tied it but other problems apperard. The main one was that `split` makes new line and I wanted to avoid that.  `replace({"\n": ""})` was a solution I tried to remove the new lines but it didn't work.